# Call super throws "super is not an expression"

Tags: java, android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata

I took up for learning implementing MVVM from Google Guide here: 
 https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#8   (posted link especially to page I'm interested in).
Since I understood implementing it in Java, I decided to switch to Kotlin. 
While initializing constructor in class extending `AndroidViewModel` I need to call `super` and it throws me following error:

> "super' is not an expression it can only be used on the left-hand side
>   of a dot ('.')"

As I googled and found similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481268/call-super-class-constructor-in-kotlin-super-is-not-an-expression) but I haven't understood it at all so I didn't solve my problem.
This my code for `ViewModel` class:

```
 class NotesViewModel private constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){

    var mRepository: NotesRepository? = null
    var mAllNotes: LiveData<List<Notes>>? = null

    init {
        super(application) // <-- here it throws me an error
        mRepository = NotesRepository(application)
        mAllNotes = mRepository!!.getAllWords()
    }

    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Notes>>{
        return mAllNotes!!
    }

    fun insert(notes: Notes){
        mRepository!!.insert(notes)
    }

}
```

So, how should I properly call super, construct a constructor? 
This is proper java code for this class:

```
public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private WordRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

    public WordViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
        mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
    }

    LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
        return mAllWords;
    }

    void insert(Word word) {
        mRepository.insert(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already call super here : `NotesViewModel private constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)`

Another problem is that your constructor is `private`

Simply make it `public` and remove `super` call from `init()`