# How to call 'super()' from a secondary constructor in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have just started using kotlin and I have a block of code in java which I have to convert to kotlin. This is the java code:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager
{
    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    private void setMyScroller() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

If there was only one constructor in this code, I could have written like this:

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager(context: Context): ViewPager(context) {

     init {
         setMyScroller()
     }

     private fun setMyScroller() {
         //some code
     }
 }
```

But, as there are two constructors and each constructor calls `super()` method, I couldn't figure out how can I convert this code to kotlin. The closest I have achieved is this:

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager(context: Context): ViewPager(context) {

     init {
         setMyScroller()
     }

     constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {
         setMyScroller()
     }

     private fun setMyScroller() {
         //some code
     }
 }
```

But, in this code, i am getting the following error in this line `super(context!!, attrs)`: 
 `primary constructor call expected`
So, how can I call `super()` from the secondary constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager: ViewPager {

    init {
        setMyScroller()
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

    private fun setMyScroller() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Notice that neither secondary constructor requires the call to `setMyScroller()`, since the `init` block will be called immediately after the `super` call.

Comment: 1. There's no primary constructor here, both constructors are secondary; 2. Neither of them needs the call, because the `init` block is called before both (but after the `super` calls).

Comment: thanks @AlexeyRomanov, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager : ViewPager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
        setMyScroller()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context) {
        setMyScroller()
    }

    private fun setMyScroller() { //some code
    }
}
```

instead of

```
 class NonSwipeableViewPager(context: Context): ViewPager(context) {

     init {
         setMyScroller()
     }

     constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {
         setMyScroller()
     }

     private fun setMyScroller() {
         //some code
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. I think I have tried this code. But, what about this line `super(context!!, attrs)` ? Even if I use your code, my question still holds. **How can i call `super()` from secondary constructor?**

Comment: @JayeshBabu this might help u [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493549/6816307)

Comment: the other answer solved my problem.. thank u anyway