# How do I pass a derived class constructor argument in a string to the base class?

Tags: kotlin, class, constructor

I want to create an exception hierarchy and specialized exceptions would need to take more / different arguments than the base exception class.

```kotlin
open class MyException(
    override val message: String,
): Exception(message)

data class MySpecialException(
    override val message: String,
    val code: Int,
): MyException("$message (with code $code)")

fun main() {
    val ex = MySpecialException("message", 123)
    println(ex.message)
}
```

When I run this, it prints

> message

and the code was lost.

I expected this to work similar to Java where I could just call `super(message + "(with code " + code + ")");` in the derived class' constructor.

Why does that happen and how can I pass the code in the message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493549/10334333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `MySpecialException` a plain class (not a data class), you'll be able to convert members to constructor parameters, and everything works as expected.

```
class MySpecialException(
    message: String,
    code: Int
) : MyException("$message (with code $code)")
```

And you may simplify `MyException` as well like this:

```
open class MyException(
    message: String
) : Exception(message)
```

The reason code from OP is not working, is because when using data class for `MySpecialException`, the overridden `message` is used when executing `println(ex.message)`. And that member contains just the value `"message"`.